# How can i append ajax response to a specific ul in a loop using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have been on this one for a week now folks. I have a newsfeed consisting of many posts. When users comment on a particular post. I want to append their comment to the specific post they commented on without refreshing the page. I have something that is currently working, but not properly.

Code below each time a user comment, the response is appended at the very last post. If it's 100 post loaded on the page and a user comment at number 1. The comment will append at the bottom at the 100 mark.

I am using the postID for my unique ID. Oh my Javascript is in my php loop too. Any help, anyone please.

```
 <ul class='post-comment-list we-comet' id='insertPostsComment$enCodePostsID'>
    <!--Post comment echo-->
        $getPostComments
    <!--Post comment echo-->
        <li>
            <a href='#' title='' class='showmore underline'>more comments</a>
        </li>
        <li id='commentForm$enCodePostsID' class='post-comment empty-comment-form'>
            <!--Comment form ajax out put-->
            <!--Comment form ajax out put-->
        </li>
 </ul>



 /*send comment to post comment reply controller with postID when button is clicked function*/
      function sendComment(e) {

      $('#submitCommentBtn').addClass('disabled');

        comment = $('textarea[name=commentField]').val();

      if(comment == ''){
          $('div#commentStatus').html('<small>comment is a required field *</small>').css('color', 'red').fadeIn();
          return false;
      }

      //get domain name only
      var urLorigin = window.location.origin;

      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: urLorigin + '/appName/profile/ajaxSendComment',
          cache: false,
          data: $('form[name=comment-form]').serialize(),
          success: function (response) {

              $('textarea[name=commentField]').val(''); //empty textarea

              /*display successs message*/
              $('div#commentStatus').html('<small>Sent&nbsp;&#10003;</small>').css('color', 'green').fadeIn();

              /*apend comment after send*/
                $('div.coment-area').each(function(){
                    //append
                    $(response).clone().appendTo($(this).find('ul#insertPostsComment$enCodePostsID'));
                });
              /*apend comment after send*/

              /*delay message closing for 5 seconds*/
              $('div#commentStatus').delay(5000).fadeOut(0);

              $('#submitCommentBtn').removeClass('disabled');
          },
          error: function(){
              alert('An unknown error occurred!');
          }
      });

      }
```

Comment: "I have something that is currently working, but not properly."  - can you please elaborate on "not properly" so that exact issue can be look after

Comment: "my Javascript is in my php loop"...so this implies you are probably creating lots of functions all called "sendComment"...can you see why that might cause problems? I get the impression, although we can't see all the necessary HTML and we can't see the loop, that you may also be creating lots of HTML elements which have the same ID, as well. Consider for a moment how you imagine the browser is going to be able to tell them apart.

Comment: But that's mostly speculation. We need to understand how the HTML and JavaScript is really structured in reality. We can't see most of the JavaScript, so there's a lack of context. We can't be sure how things are being executed or what impact that will have. Please try to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can understand what is going on.

Comment: @ Bhushan The code i posted below the question, that's what i am having trouble with.

Comment: @ADyson the function in the loop was the problem. I was basically creating hundreds of functions, so it was iterating and appending to last one. Thanks a million man!

Comment: Yes. If you create lots of functions with the same name then JavaScript will consider that you are simply overwriting the function definition each time, and so it will use the last version it finds in the page as the one to execute when some other code tries to call that function.